# Django ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django

In my model I have:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

I'm trying to create the Poll object and store tags like so:

```
Tags = []
for splitTag in splitTags:
    tag = Tag(name = splitTag.lower())
    tag.save()
    Tags.append(tag)
```

How do I set the `Tags` array and assign it to `tags`?

I have tried:

```
    poll = Poll(topic=topic, tags = Tags)
    poll.save()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, it should be more like this:

```
models.py

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Poll(models.Model):
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

in views.py:

poll = Poll(topic="My topic")
poll.save()
for splitTag in splitTags:
    tag = Tag(name = splitTag.lower())
    tag.save()
    poll.tags.add(tag)
poll.save()
```

Answer (score 3):

I see that you're trying to build your own tag system, but I think it might help if you take a look at an already existing one.

http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/

I use that in my apps and it has an awesome api to boot.